# putObject statement can't upload file to aliyun OSS

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I write a function to upload video file to aliyun OSS. the function works fine in spring boot but can't work in standalone tomcat. The problem is caused by the statement `ossClient.putObject(bucket,Objectname,file.getInputStream());`

Could anybody tell me what is wrong?

In spring boot I run this function and successfully upload files to aliyun OSS. then I export code to war file and deployed to tomcat then can't work.
it throws 500 internal server error when without throwable exception.

```
@Controller
public class UploadVideoController {
    private final static org.slf4j.Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UploadVideoController.class);
    @Autowired
    private VideoFileRepository videoFileRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;
    @Autowired
    private VideoFileInSolrRepository videoSolrRepo;

    String endpoint = "http://oss-cn-zhangjiakou.aliyuncs.com";
    String accessKeyId = "my id";
    String accessKeySecret = "my secret";
    String bucket = "studytech";
    String aliyunURL = "https://studytech.oss-cn-zhangjiakou.aliyuncs.com/";

    @RequestMapping("/videoUpload")
    public String UploadPage(Model model) {
        return "uploadVideoPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/doVideoUpload")
    public String doupload(Model model, @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) throws IOException {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        ApplicationUser au = applicationUserRepository.findByUsername(authentication.getName());
        StringBuilder fileNames = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder fileNotUpload = new StringBuilder();
        Path path;

        log.info("realPathtoUploads = {}", endpoint);

        for (MultipartFile file : files) {
            OSS ossClient = new OSSClientBuilder().build(endpoint, accessKeyId, accessKeySecret);
            String Objectname = file.getOriginalFilename();

            path = Paths.get(Objectname);
            String filetype = Files.probeContentType(path);
            VideoFile vf = videoFileRepository.findByFileName(Objectname);
            if (filetype.equals("video/mp4") && vf == null) {
                try {
                    ossClient.putObject(bucket, Objectname, file.getInputStream());
                    VideoFile document = new VideoFile(file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getContentType(),
                            aliyunURL + file.getOriginalFilename(), "test");
                    document.setAppuser(au);
                    au.getVideoFilelist().add(document);
                    videoFileRepository.save(document);
                    VideoFileInSolr solrdocument = new VideoFileInSolr(file.getOriginalFilename(),
                            aliyunURL + file.getOriginalFilename());
                    videoSolrRepo.save(solrdocument);
                    fileNames.append(file.getOriginalFilename() + " ");

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("user or file not found");

                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } finally {
                    ossClient.shutdown();
                }

            } else {
                fileNotUpload.append(file.getOriginalFilename() + " ");
            }
        }
        if (fileNames != null) {
            model.addAttribute("msg1", "Successfully uploaded files: " + fileNames.toString());
        }
        if (fileNotUpload != null) {
            model.addAttribute("msg2", "Files alread exist or file extension is not .mp4: " + fileNotUpload.toString());
        }
        return "uploadVideoPage";
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is solved:

Comment: the problem is solved:change the version of jdom in pom.xml<!-- jdom，aliyun OSS can only use1.1.x version -->
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
    <!--<version>2.0.2</version>-->
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>